# Can you list users in Meteor without a login system?

Tags: javascript, meteor

For example, if I did a chatroom where all you ahve to do is enter a username (so you don't log in), can I still somehow list out all the people in that chatroom? How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the normal `Meteor.users` collection, it would probably be easiest to create your own collection for such simple authentication.

If you wanted to make it really simple (most likely, as long as you didn't care if 2 people have the same name), just store the name as a property of a chat room message document.

**Edit - answer to comment:**

To detect when a user disconnects, you can add an event handler in your publish function like this:

```
Meteor.publish('some_collection', function(){
  var connectionId = this.connection ? this.connection.id : 'server';
  this._session.socket.on("close", Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(){
    // deal with connectionId closing
  }));
});
```

Comment: How do you see if that user is online or not? Like if they left, how would you be able to detect it?

Comment: @yimmy Added example for user disconnection from collection

Answer (score 0):

You can do that.
Simply `publish` all users and every coming client should `subscribe`.

#### server:

```
Meteor.publish('allUsers', function(){
  return Meteor.users.find({},{fields:{profile:1}});
})
```

#### client :

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
  Meteor.subscribe('allUsers');
})

Template.listOfUsers.users = function(){
  return Meteor.users.find();
}
```

This is very basic example, which should be adjusted to your needs.

Comment: So you can see the users on your site even if I don't directly save any user info into the user collection?

Comment: No, first you need to save information about connected users to some collection. Above answer is about publishing all users from `Meteor.user` collection. Check package [meteor-user-status](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status) to get info about online users.